# Find the item in an array with the largest property

Tags: rust

I have a struct like this

```
struct Point {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
}

impl Point {
    fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Self {
        Point { x, y }
    }
}
```

And an array like this

```
[Point::new(1, 1), Point::new(4, 2), Point::new(2, 9)];
```

How do I pull the item with largest `point.x` from this array?

Answer (score 12):

Use [`Iterator::max_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max_by_key):

```
let a = [Point::new(1, 1), Point::new(4, 2), Point::new(2, 9)];
let max = a.iter().max_by_key(|p| p.x);
```

There's also [`Iterator::min_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.min_by_key).

See also:

- [How can min_by_key or max_by_key be used with references to a value created during iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49311954/155423)
- [Using max_by_key on a vector of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37127209/155423)
- [What is the idiomatic way to get the index of a maximum or minimum floating point value in a slice or Vec in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53903318/155423)