# How can min_by_key or max_by_key be used with references to a value created during iteration?

Tags: rust

I have an iterator that maps over some values, creating tuples on the way. I need to get the maximum by one of the elements on the tuple (**which is not `Copy`**), but interior references are getting in the way (as [was expected when it got stabilised](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27724)).

How can I make something like this work?

```
// Not a Copy type!
#[derive(Ord, PartialOrd, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct t(i8);

fn main() {
    // This works
    let v = vec![(t(0),), (t(1),)];
    v.iter().min_by_key(|v| &v.0);

    // This doesn't
    let v = vec![0, 1];
    v.iter().map(|i| (t(*i),)).min_by_key(|v| &v.0);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=540af072a396722a50fa9c3704d6a248&version=stable)

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:12:47
   |
12 |     v.iter().map(|i| (t(*i),)).min_by_key(|v| &v.0);
   |                                               ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the body at 12:43...
  --> src/main.rs:12:43
   |
12 |     v.iter().map(|i| (t(*i),)).min_by_key(|v| &v.0);
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:12:47
   |
12 |     v.iter().map(|i| (t(*i),)).min_by_key(|v| &v.0);
   |                                               ^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the method call at 12:5...
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
12 |     v.iter().map(|i| (t(*i),)).min_by_key(|v| &v.0);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that a type/lifetime parameter is in scope here
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
12 |     v.iter().map(|i| (t(*i),)).min_by_key(|v| &v.0);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They cannot. As values flow through iterator adapters, they are moved. Moving a value causes any references to it to be invalidated. You are attempting to take a reference to a value that only exists in the iterator pipeline; the reference cannot live long enough. This is equivalent to this basic example:

```
(0..9).map(|x| &x)
```

You will need to use [`Iterator::min_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.min_by):

```
v.iter().map(|i| (X(*i),)).min_by(|a, b| a.0.cmp(&b.0));
```

This works because the returned value from the closure is an `Ordering` with no references to the original values.