# How do I get the key associated with the maximum value of a Rust HashMap?

Tags: rust

For example, given the data:

```
2 : 4  
1 : 3  
5 : 2
```

The function would return 2 since its value (4) is the highest.

I am doing:

```rust
let mut max_val = 0;
let mut max_key = "";
for (k, v) in a_hash_map.iter() {
    if *v > max_val {
        max_key = k;
        max_val = *v;
    }
}
```

Is there a nicer or quicker or simpler way to do this?

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Iterate through all the key-value pairs in the hashmap, comparing them by the values, keeping only the key of the maximum:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn example<K, V>(a_hash_map: &HashMap<K, V>) -> Option<&K>
where
    V: Ord,
{
    a_hash_map
        .iter()
        .max_by(|a, b| a.1.cmp(&b.1))
        .map(|(k, _v)| k)
}

fn main() {
    let map: HashMap<_, _> = vec![(2, 4), (1, 3), (5, 2)].into_iter().collect();
    dbg!(example(&map));
}
```

See also:

- [How do I create a map from a list in a functional way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30441698/155423)
- [How can min_by_key or max_by_key be used with references to a value created during iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49311954/155423)

Comment: Why do I need the ```.1``` at the a and b int he max_by?

Comment: @SzabóÁron Because both `a` and `b` are pairs `(key, value)`.

Answer (score 15):

```
let key_with_max_value = a_hashmap.iter().max_by_key(|entry | entry.1).unwrap();

dbg!(key_with_max_value.0);
```

You will need to do better error handling. This code just does an `unwrap`, expecting that there would be at least one element.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps you can have a try with this: `if let Some(max) = a_hash_map.keys().max(){println!("max:{}", max);}`

Comment: This returns the key with the highest value, not the key max associated value. I'll make that more clear in the question.